# Can not resolve import javafx.util.Pair in android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am not able to resolve the issue javafx. When I import this package it is showing `can't resolve javafx.util.pair`. while I have configured properly in gradle its working in other's system.

Comment: Have you configured it properly, though? We have no way to verify that.

Comment: The same code is working in other system, i am not finding the exact problem.

Comment: Show us some of the code, then.

Answer (score 14):

This is because `javafx.util.Pair` is not a part of OpenJDK which is distributed and used by Android Studio. You need to use Oracle JDK which include JavaFX where it contains `javafx.util.Pair`. Try to change your Android Studio JDK from your setting.

Or alternatively, you can use [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) or using [android.util.Pair](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair)

Comment: How do you expect to use the Oracle JDK on an Android device? This does not seem to make sense to me.

Comment: @mipa: That's what my first thought when reading the question. Android didn't contains any javafx, cmiiw. But after reading the op question again, I think op want to do some Java coding which is not directly related with Android.

Comment: The question is tagged with "android" and to me it sounds as if he has taken some working Java code from somewhere and tries to use it on Android now. But you are right, if the OP does not make his real intention clear, it's all just guesswork.

Comment: when i check on my system only JRE is installed not JDK(c://program file/java/jre).And when i install java only JRE is Installing not JDK. I think this is creating problem , please guide me how to resolve it,

Answer (score 6):

Create your own pair class as follows -

```
public class Pair<T,U> {
    private final T key;
    private final U value;

    public Pair(T key, U value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public U getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got the answer, I checked the following points
1. Checked java location, i found only JRE folder is showing no JDK.
2. Open android studio then goto file-->project structure--> jdk path
   there recommended option is selected.

What i did?
I searched the suitable java/jdk version for my system which was java 1.8.0 (Java SE 8u191 ) in [jdk-8u191-windows-x64.exe](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). i downloaded and installed now i found JRE and JDK both installed successfully.

Now i opened android studio then goto file-->project structure--> jdk path (c://programfile/java/jdk1/8.0) browse the jdk path and unchecked the recommended setting.

Sync the project problem resolved.